# Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, sonarqube

```
public String buildSolrDateFormat(final String strDate) {

        final String dateFormat1 = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9]";
        final String dateFormat2 = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]";
        final String dateFormat3 = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]";
        final String dateFormat = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]";
        final String solrFormat = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]T[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]Z";

        DateTimeFormatter formatter;
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
        String formattedDate = "";
        if (strDate.matches(dateFormat1)) {
            formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
            dateTime = formatter.withZoneUTC().parseDateTime(strDate);
            formattedDate = dateTime.toString();
        } else if (strDate.matches(dateFormat2)) {
            formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS");
            dateTime = formatter.withZoneUTC().parseDateTime(strDate);
            formattedDate = dateTime.toString();
        } else if (strDate.matches(dateFormat3)) {
            formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            dateTime = formatter.withZoneUTC().parseDateTime(strDate);
            formattedDate = dateTime.toString();
        } else if (strDate.matches(solrFormat)) {
            formattedDate = strDate;
        } else if (strDate.matches(dateFormat)) {
            formattedDate = strDate.concat("T00:00:00Z");
        }

        return formattedDate;
    }
```

I have to write test case for this method and below is the test case for the above method. Everything is fine on my IDE it runs without an errors in my IDE but when I try to build application on Sonar Plans it throws error with this test case on logs.

```
    @Test
    void testBuildSolrDateFormat() {
        String formattedDate1 = jsonMetaDataService.buildSolrDateFormat("2022-11-15 14:42:28.7");
        assertEquals("2022-11-15T14:42:28.700Z", formattedDate1);
        String formattedDate2 = jsonMetaDataService.buildSolrDateFormat("2022-11-15 14:42:28.74");
        assertEquals("2022-11-15T14:42:28.740Z", formattedDate2);
        String formattedDate3 = jsonMetaDataService.buildSolrDateFormat("2022-11-15 14:42:28.743");
        assertEquals("2022-11-15T14:42:28.743Z", formattedDate3);
        String formattedDate5 = jsonMetaDataService.buildSolrDateFormat("2022-11-15T14:42:28Z");
        assertEquals("2022-11-15T14:42:28Z", formattedDate5);
        String formattedDate6 = jsonMetaDataService.buildSolrDateFormat("2022-11-15");
        assertEquals("2022-11-15T00:00:00Z", formattedDate6);
    }
```

This throws **Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here** errors on **Sonar Logs** while it's fine on my IDE ( NO ERRORS ON IDE)

Comment: I don't see any argument matchers in your code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Clearly, the error refers to code you haven't shown here. That error is from Mockito.  Perhaps you have a setup method in this test class that is doing some stubbing?